# interpreting results of svyglm

Tags: r

I am running a regression model and seeking to interpret the results of svyglm, for a continuous outcome variable and explanatory variables that are both categorical and continuous, when complex sampling design weights are accounted for. Are the results the same as an interpretation with linear regression analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - a survey GLM is interpreted in the exact same way as a normal GLM. It's basically just the standard errors / AIC correctly accounting for the clustering etc.